# RelayFindGraphQLTags failing to compile even though requirements are satisfied

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I am attempting to compile Relay, however it is not recognizing my graphql queries as valid.

Sample query:

```
const testQuery = graphql`query CustomersQuery {
   customers(first: 20) {
     nodes {
       id
       name
     }
   }
 }`
```

The project is on CRA 2.0 with Typescript.

The build script is as follows:

```
"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql --language typescript --extensions ts tsx js jsx"
```

And here is the error I received:

```
Parse error: Error: RelayFindGraphQLTags: Operation names in graphql tags must be prefixed with the module name and end in "Mutation", "Query", or "Subscription". Got `CustomersQuery` in module `Main`.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? It feels like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1718#issuecomment-301836291). Basically says the the name of your query must be your filename + "Query". So for App.tsx the name of the query would have to be "AppQuery".

> Note that the name of the query must be <FileName>Query. So query clientQuery { ... } will only work if the query is in a file named client.js.